# why does gearman client slow down after I add more servers?

Tags: python, gearman, ports

I am using Gearman to distribute jobs to my servers. Initially when I only had 8 workers they would get a steady stream of jobs. However when I doubled the amount of servers the workers sporadically get jobs. Occasionally they pause for a few minutes.

Initially I thought it has something to do with the number of backlog connections so I changed it to 200 (as opposed to 32). That did not fix the problem.

I am submitting jobs with Geaman's submit_multiple_jobs. Like so:

```
logging.warning("Jobs ready")
requests=gm_client.submit_multiple_jobs(jobs)
logging.warning("Jobs sent")
```

I am using gearman with python
Has anyone had similar issues? 
Any Idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Gearman doesn't distribute jobs in a round robin, instead they all go into a queue and as the workers loop through the queue to see any jobs awaiting actioning they get the jobs then. What is probably happening is that the one worker is actioning the jobs faster than the other workers are picking it up, in this sort of situation I would actually recommend reducing the number of workers as they will still be using significant system resources even without any jobs to go through.